# Dropping the first or last index from an array without getting an "Out of Bounds" Error

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been assigned to create a program that in one of its methods I have to prompt the user to input an index that they would like to drop the value of. My problem is that when I try to drop index 0 then I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at index -1. So to fix that I tried `i <= currentSize + 1` which fixed the index 0 problem, but then with the last index I get an out of bounds error because the currentSize is one more than they array size. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//This method drops the value of a selected index in the array.
private static void Drop ()
{
     int m =0;
     System.out.println("Choose an index that you would like to drop the value of:");    
     if(input.hasNextInt())
     {
         m = input.nextInt();
         for(int pos = 0; pos < values.length; pos++)
         {
             if(pos == m)
             {
                 for(int i = pos+1; i<=currentSize+1; i++)
                 {
                     values[i-1]= values[i];
                     values[i]=0;
                 }
                 currentSize--;
                 break;
             }
             else if(pos == 0)
             {
                 System.out.println("ERROR: There is not an index at the specified location.");
             }  
         }
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("ERROR: Please input a integer value.");
     }
}
```

Comment: When removing elements from a list or array, it's convention to iterate through the list backwards. This is because if the list automatically resizes itself (like an ArrayList), you're not skipping over elements.

Comment: What does `currentSize` represent? I don't see it initialized anywhere in the code.

Comment: it would be better if you indent your code

Answer (score 2):

Here's an efficient and compact way to do it:

```
private static void drop(int[] arr, int index, int currentSize) {
    System.arraycopy(arr, index + 1, arr, index, currentSize - index - 1);
}
```

This effectively shifts the array elements to the left,
starting from the specified index + 1 until `currentSize`.
It works with any valid index,
so for example for an array of size 3,
it works with indexes 0, 1, 2.
It doesn't check boundaries,
so in this example index -1 or 3 would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Using this function,
you could simplify your code to:

```
private static void mainInputLoop() {
    System.out.println("Choose an index that you would like to drop the value of:");
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        index = input.nextInt();
        drop(values, index, currentSize--);
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Please input a integer value.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright I did this and if I go back to add another value in into the new blank index the program will write over all the index values between the empty spot and the spot that was previously dropped. So ,for instance, if I add 4 values in to the values array with length 5 and then drop say index 1, then when I go to add a value again the program will write over  index 2 first.

Comment: Values should be added at `arr[currentSize]`, provided the array has capacity for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.arrayCopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to simplify your code.